# Match the results of an unknown data smoothing method using Python

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, smoothing

I'm trying to replicate the smoothing function of the closed-source software application, MATLAB, in order to match its data smoothing results.

I tried to take a look at the MATLAB [smoothing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/smoothing-data.html) documentation, but given my experience, I don't know how to construct a formula to get those results.

#### Raw data examples

```
s1 = [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.969. 1. 0.969. 0.938. 0.750. 0.563]
s2 = [0.500, 0.313, 0.500, 0.656, 0.719, 0.969, 1.000, 0.969, 1.000, 1.000, 1.000, 1.000, 1.000, 1.000, 1.000, 1.00]
```

#### Target results after smoothing

Note: I rounded the results to 2 digits for readability.

```
st1 = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.996,, 0.988, 0.975, 0.941, 0.873, 0.768, 0.688]
st2 = [0.396, 0.416, 0.525, 0.666, 0.775, 0.883, 0.949, 0.973, 0.992, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00]
```

#### Attempt

I tried different filters from `scipy.ndfilters` but I do not get the exact target results.

Note: I used strings to be able to compare the data fast visually.

```
from scipy.ndimage import uniform_filter1d as filter

s = [0.500, 0.313, 0.500, 0.656, 0.719, 0.969, 1.000, 0.969, 1.000, 1.000, 1.000, 1.000, 1.000, 1.000, 1.000, 1.00]

st = "0.396 | 0.416 | 0.525 | 0.666 | 0.775 | 0.883 | 0.949 | 0.973 | 0.992 | 1.00 | 1.00 | 1.00 | 1.00 | 1.00 | 1.00 | 1.00"


def moving_avg(arr):
    for i in range(1, 6):
        z = ""
        csm = filter(arr, i, axis=-1)

        for num in csm:
            y = round(num*1000)/1000
            z += str(y) + " | "

        print(str(i) + ": " + z[:-3] + "\n")

moving_avg(s)
print("Y: " + str(st))


def test_smoothing(arr, num):
    sumup = 0
    for item in arr[num-2:num+3]:
        sumup += item
        print(item)
    res = sumup / 5
    print(res)
```

Image of the smoothing/unsmoothing problem for illustration:

[image: Data unsmoothed and smoothed illustration]

Comment: The problem is that there's fairly little data here - even if someone comes up with a way to reverse engineer some smoothing function from the few data points you provided, odds are that it's not actually the smoothing function you were using before, unless it's something very trivial. Do you have access to the Matlab script that was used previously? You don't have access to the Matlab software, but sharing the original code or command would help someone who knows both Python libraries and Matlab to find the appropriate smoothing function (if it is available).

Answer (score 0):

The data set is an array of 16 x 16 fields: `array = [[0] * 16] * 16`. This will be filled by data between 0 and 1.

From the tests I conducted (see below) I recognised that the data smoothing window is set to 3 in x and y direction and figured out how the smoothing occurs.

The final formula is:

```py
smoothed_value = (raw_target * 4 + raw(above + below + left + right)*2 +
                  raw(upleft + upright + lowleft + lowright)*1) / 16
```

[image: Data smoothing details by demonstration in spreadsheet]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thank you for contributing. In future, please keep answers brief while including sufficient detail. Avoid adding generic words like "edited" or "update" to an edited post. Users can see the edit history. You also don't need to add a [valedictory](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/valedictory) or other pleasantries (like greetings or "thank you") in the body of your posts.